# Add attributes from list in thymeleaf

Tags: java, attributes, thymeleaf

I have a `List<Tags>` in java and would like to add each `Tag` to a single div in the template.
The Tag class looks like this(kinda):

```
public class Tag {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    public Tag(String key, String value) { this.key = key; this.value = value; }
    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

The result I want: `<div tag1Key="tag1Value" tag2Key="tag2Value"></div>` except the list can contain X amount of Tags.
I do not have info on what tags can appear.

How would one solve this problem? My first thought was a `th:each="tag: ${list}"` but then the tags(attrubutes) would appear on different divs...

My second idea was the `th:attr="${list.get(0).getKey()}=${list.get(0).getValue()}"` but then I would need to hard code the amount of tags the list can contain which is dynamic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `th:attr` with [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

In your controller generate a string from the attributes:

```
model.addAttribute("attributes", "attr1=something,attr2='bla bla'");
```

In the template assign it with preprocessing (two underscores) which basically means that it will first replace the variable and then evaluate the `th:attr` expression

```
<div th:attr="__${attributes}__">
```